# Track Intent.ACTION_DELETE is successfully uninstall the app or not

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, uninstallation, android-package-managers

This is my code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packagename));
startActivity(intent);
```

With this code, android prompts a dialog box to ask the user to uninstall the app, with two options **Uninstall** or **Cancel**.

Here how I tack or determine that the user choose **Uninstall** or **Cancel**.

How can ensure that the app is uninstalled?

**Important NOT**: The packages or apps that I uninstall here are other apps installed on the device.

Answer (score 1):

> How can ensure that the app is uninstalled?

Store the package name of apps that you uninstall and after some time check is the app is installed by using the package name.

> Here how I tack or determine that the user choose Uninstall or Cancel.

After some time check if app is installed or not by using the app package name. If it is not found then user has uninstalled. If it is found then user has pressed cancel.

Use this function to check if app is installed.

```
private fun String.isAppInstalled(activity: Activity): Boolean {
    val pm = activity.packageManager!!
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(this, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
        return true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
         
    }
    return false
}
```

Usage : `"packageName".isAppInstalled(Activity)`

Returns true if app is present.